# How can I export a model from Unity to three.js?

Tags: unity, javascript, blender, three.js

I want to buy some assets from the Unity asset store and use them in my three.js project, but I am not sure what the best way to go about this is. Some cursory googling got me [this](http://helloenjoy.com/2013/from-unity-to-three-js/), but Collada Exporter does not support the latest version of Unity afaik. I have also tried some other exporters such as [this one](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/22250), but the objects I get out of it are buggy (mirrored pieces not rendering etc.). Ideally my workflow would be Unity -> Blender -> three.js (as json). I know there is a three.js blender exporter, so I suppose the missing part is going from Unity to Blender. I would also like animations to be exported.

Does anyone have experience with a workflow successfully exporting assets from Unity to three.js?

Comment: IANAL, but make sure you read the licenses for the assets you intend to purchase so that you are absolutely certain you can use them outside of Unity.

Comment: @XGundam05 AFAIK it is fine because the license for the Unity store states that purchased goods may be used for electronic games and other interactive media. There is no mention of inside or outside of Unity, so I assume it does not matter as long as I'm not distributing the asset itself separately.

Answer (score 3):

I wrote an [Unity3D to Three.js exporter](http://threejsexporter.nickjanssen.com) that does exactly what you ask for.